# C# Automation Edge Browser - using Edge Driver - auto testing program - Failure: No matching capabilities found (SessionNotCreated)

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge, browser-automation

Greetings stackoverflow community,

I am trying to compile and run the programcode from this website:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7bdafd2a-be91-4f4f-a33d-6bea2f889e09/c-sample-for-automating-ms-edge-chromium-browser-using-edge-web-driver

I followed all the instructions listed in the link and set my paths were I wanted them.

The program and the edge driver starts running, but then an error appears.

"An error exeption "System.InvalidOperationException" appeared in WebDriver.dll.

Further Inforamtion: session not created: No matching capabilities found (SessionNotCreated)"

This is the code from my program, more or less copied from the link above:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var anaheimService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\edgedriver_win64", "msedgedriver.exe"); 
           // user need to pass the driver path here....
           var anaheimOptions = new ChromeOptions
           {
               // user need to pass the location of new edge app here....
               BinaryLocation = @"
        C: \Program Files(x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe "
           };

        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(anaheimService, anaheimOptions); -- error appears at this line
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https: //google.com/");
        Console.WriteLine(driver.Title.ToString());
        driver.Close();
     }
   }
}
```

I would really appreciate your help!

Best Regards
Max

Answer (score 2):

The article you refer to is a bit out of date. Now we don't need to use `ChromeDriver` to automate Edge. You can refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=c-sharp) about how to use WebDriver to automate Microsoft Edge.

I recommend using Selenium 4. Here I install Selenium 4.1.0 NuGet package and the sample C# code is like below:

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;

namespace WebDriverTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var options = new EdgeOptions();
            options.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe";    
            var driver = new EdgeDriver(@"C:\edgedriver_win64", options);

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");
            Console.WriteLine(driver.Title.ToString());
            driver.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I will try it out.

Comment: Hi @blitzmax Is there any update about the test result?

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't work out with that kind of webpage. I could convince my company to use a newer version of VS that we can use the new implemented Edge Browser. - But thanks for your help!